# how change active class on a listItem using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, selecteditem, css

please see the demo below :
http://www.templateaccess.com/demos/walkin/
i bought this template and really really could n't find a way how does active class on menu_nav li work?
that menu_nav html is like this :

```
  <div class="menu_nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="index-2.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="blog.html"><span>Blog</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="support.html"><span>Support</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

and it's css :

```
/* menu */
.menu_nav { margin:0; padding:50px 0 0; float:right; width:auto; height:43px;}
.menu_nav ul { list-style:none; padding:0; height:43px;}
.menu_nav ul li { margin:0; padding:0 0 0 2px; float:left;}
.menu_nav ul li a { display:block; margin:0; padding:0 0 0 20px; font-size:16px; line-height:19px; font-weight:normal; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; text-transform:none; text-align:center;}
.menu_nav ul li a span { display:block; padding:12px 20px 12px 0; height:19px;}
.menu_nav ul li.active a, .menu_nav ul li a:hover { color:#fff; background:url(images/menu_a_l.png) no-repeat left top;}
.menu_nav ul li.active a span, .menu_nav ul li a:hover span { background:url(images/menu_a_r.png) no-repeat right top;}
```

as you see there is a class named 'active' that moves by clicking on every menu and never jumps to home menu during postbacks.
there is no jquery or javascript about that.
how does it work?
in my asp.net that active class does not work, so i add the jquery below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.menu_nav ul li').click(function () { $(this).addClass('active'); alert('a'); });
    }); 
</script>
```

but during postbacks i lose active class on selected item.
any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the '.active' class on the `client-side`, so as soon as your page does a full `postback` everything is being re-created on the `server-side`. If you want to prevent that from happening, use an `UpdatePanel` and only refresh the page content (leaving the navigation menu intact).

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="menu_nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="index-2"><a href="index-2.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li class="blog"><a href="blog.html"><span>Blog</span></a></li>
    <li class="support"><a href="support.html"><span>Support</span></a></li>
    <li class="about"><a href="about.html"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var location = window.location.href,
    nav = $('.menu_nav');
    $('li', nav).each(function() {
        var index = location.indexOf($(this).prop('class'));
        if (index != -1) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but how does that html work without this jquery codes?

Comment: also, still does not work. during postbacks i lose active class!

Comment: @SilverLight What ever you do with JS is lost at postback unless you do something server side as well but there's no server side code in you post so it's hard to see what you've tried and therefor impossible to see where your attempts failed

Comment: i still did n't write any server side codes!how can i add active class on selected item with server side codes?

Answer (score 1):

That `active` class is set manually on each page for the menu items. So you don't need JavaScript to set it unless you are using AJAX to get the new page and display it.

Your menu seemed to work fine for me, every-page has it's menu item properly styled.

Comment: ok thanks, now i know how it works in html project. but in asp.net project i have a master page.what can i do about that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ASP.NET` but in `PHP` I would create an `if/then` statement in each menu `li` element like this: `<li <?php if ($page == 'Home') { echo " class='active'"; } ?>>`